# Cutting method, where shaving stays attached from one side

Tags: machining, metals, cutting, metalwork

Usually shaving goes out in front of the tool, being connected only along the cutting tool width.

Im interested in another case, when shaving is moved to one side and it stays connected to the material (metal), for the whole length of this partial cut, unlike traditional method.

This probably could be achieved with a cutting tool being angled, and directed with its sharp part at an angle to both, the material and the cutting trajectory, to not to rip away the shaving as it moves. Probably a rolling sharp disk blade would help, to avoid quick dulling of the cutters sharp edge.

Any additional info about how to make such a change to a material surface would help.

Comment: What are you cutting? Sounds like what endmills and lathe tool lead angles, rake angles, and clearance angles are for.

Comment: @DKNguyen metal. copper or aluminium

Comment: The appropriate lead and rake angle will do this but needs an appropriate depth of cut and feed rate for the material. Some materials just will not produce stringy chips which is considered desirable. Usually in machining metal this is bad so they use a chip breaker since the very strong long stringy chip wraps, and catches and ruins surface finish or worse tanggles the machine.

Comment: @DKNguyen i want all the 'chip' to stay attached to the material by its side. If cutting tool is 3mm and cut length is 30mm, then the chip distance from the material at most is 3mm. I expect that usual cutting tools with 80deg or so will not allow this, and a special tool with a sharp edge of 15deg or so will be needed

Comment: No guarantee the chip won't curl. They definitely do on anything on a lathe.

Comment: @DKNguyen i understsnd this. But in 3mm it cant curl much, unlike usual chip that can be tens of cm long. I expect its curl to depend on its distance from the material (cutter's width), and angle of the cut

Comment: It curls based on feed rate, depth of cut too.